# alternative for < in mysql command

Tags: mysql, ant, build, exec, configuration-files

is there any alternative for < in the mysql command?
Thank you in advance.

```
  <exec executable="mysql" dir="${mysql.path}" failonerror="true">
      <arg value="--user=pro"></arg>
      <arg value="--password=pro"></arg>
      <arg value="pro"></arg>
      <arg value="&lt; prdump.sql"></arg>
  </exec>
     <echo message="DB backup/restore"/>
```

Error:

build failed, exec returned: 1

Comment: The ANT documentation for the exec task has a "input" option for specifying file input See: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Comment: You could also consider using the ANT sql task to connect directly to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding

```
-e "source prdump.sql"
```

as the final arg.

But note that MySQL will be running in batch mode & not using the history file. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html (Actually that applies to using < too)